# Trying to built correct xpath

Tags: css, xml, xpath

I have a problem with building an xpath, maybe you have an idea.

[image]

I am working on some automation and I really need to get the full path to this "delete reminder" button, but it must be also checking name, which is located in span 7 (`Dh3M5EdV6l` in this case). Tried everything, nothing works, it must be that name somewhere included, but I just have no idea how to combine values from 2 spans into one path. Is it possible?

CSS might work too

```
<li class="row-fluid" data-target="upcoming_reminder_row">
        <div class="span7">Dh3M5EdV6l</div>
        <div class="span3">Oct 10, 2025 12:00 PM EDT</div>
        <div class="span2">
                  <div class="pull-right">
                       <i class="icon-Edit" data-target="edit_reminder" data-value="67">
                       </i>
                       <i class="icon-Close" data-target="delete_reminder" data-value="67">
                       </i>
                  </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, we need to locate the `li` element that has the "span7" element with an appropriate text. Then, we'll locate the desired button inside it. Both things in a single XPath expression:

```
//li[@data-target = "upcoming_reminder_row" and div[@class = "span7"] = "Dh3M5EdV6l"]//i[@data-target = "delete_reminder"]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, it actually found it!
Unfortunately, it came up as a 'Document' type and for some reason ended up unclickable :\
Found a workaround though, just using this locator "//*[@id="upcoming_reminders"]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/div[3]/div/i[2]" in a loop until everything gets deleted in the setup, and one more time in a teardown. Works like a clock now. Thank you anyway, now I know how to do it!